# Wordpress User Query By ACF & Multiple Values?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to figure out the correct logic to accomplish what I want to do. Basically I have a list of types of art work and a list of locations that are presented to a user via a checkbox for each option. I want to be able to allow users to select multiple types of artwork and a location and have WP_USER_QUERY pull all users who are assigned these types via a ACF field. I can kind of get this to work, but I can't seem to get it to work in a "or" solution, as in if someone selects multiple types of artwork it should show option 1 and option 2 and option 3, not if the user has option 1, option 2 and option 3 assigned to the profile...if that makes sense?

Here's what I have so far:

```
         $args = array(
        'role' => 'artist',
        'meta_key' => 'last_name',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );

    if (isset($_POST['mediumType'])){
        // WP_User_Query arguments
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
           'key' => 'artist_medium',
           'value'=> $_POST['mediumType'],
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    };

    if (isset($_POST['locationType'])){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'=>'studio_region_location',
            'value' =>$_POST['locationType'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    };

    $user_query = new WP_USER_QUERY ($args);
```

Thanks for any help.
This *kinda* works, except for some reason it wont limit its search to the assigned key, isntead it will search every field in the profile and return the result, instead of those explicibly in the "artist_medium" or "studio_region_location"

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but check out the sample `Multiple custom user fields handling` on [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#custom-field-parameters), specifically that `meta_query` is an array with one key called `relation` set to `OR`, and subsequent entries in the array are the arrays like you have above.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That was helpful. I think now my only issue is figuring out how to push the checkbox values into $_POST as a array

Comment: For this, I'd skip the `$_POST` for now and just manually build a query that works. You can use [this to see the last query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110269/12496) which might be helpful to paste into a MySQL editor. You might also have to manually inspect the `wp_usermeta` table to make sure what is in there is what you get. This query **is not** interpreted by ACF, remember, only MySQL, so the raw values in the database are important, even if ACF gives you different results on the page

Comment: Thank you so much :)